# scrolling ajax load more records feature within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to make a scrolling ajax load more records feature but ...

I am in an iframe of a external site. The parent site is setting the height of the iframe to the hight of its content (my content) automatically. How can I detect if the user has scrolled the parent site down until the end of my iframe's contend?

I have tried several solutions on the web but all of them are just not working from within an iframe.

Here an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57oyyoc7/1/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
           // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
        console.log("load more");
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't. It has to be javascript from the parent to detect this in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to do this. I didn't understand your question correctly in my comment :

```
$(parent.window).scroll(function(e){
    if($(window.parent.document).scrollTop() >= $('html').height()) {
        console.log("load more from parent");
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/vbp6bofn/)